# SpringBoot rest service error handling

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger

There are multiple ways to send custom message in error response of rest api call.
Which is the best way out of these :

1.One way is to use `io.swagger.annotations` like 
`@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "error message", response=ErrorDescription.class) })`
above method signature.

2.Another way is to define `@ControllerAdvice` over global exception hanlder.

Which is the better way of two.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot the third one: define custom `exception` that scope only your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach with the swagger annotation **won't handle** your errors in your application. It's just for documentation purposes so that you can see how your API behaves in an error case. With this annotation, you customize your `swagger-ui.html` page for your REST endpoint and map the error code to a specific response object and add a custom description for your clients.

To really **handle** e.g. exceptions with self-defined response types and message you can use `@ControllerAdvice` and define the result types and messages. In addition, I would also use the Swagger annotation to write some text about the error case and tell the client which response object he can expect.

The following blog post might help you for writing your `@ControllerAdvice` clas: http://niels.nu/blog/2016/controller-advice-exception-handlers.html